# Programatically creating edges in Neo4j with python

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm trying to generate nodes and edges for some chemicals and associated reactions in neo4j with python but am hitting a problem with node/relationship creation...

My code...

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase, basic_auth

driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost", auth=basic_auth("neo4j", "password"))
session = driver.session()
    
def addReactionNeo4j(reagents, products, reaction):
    cypher = "CREATE (%s:Reaction {RXNid:\"%s\", name:\"%s\"})" % (reaction[0],reaction[1],reaction[2])
    session.run(cypher)
    print cypher

    for reagent in reagents:
        cypher = "CREATE (%s:Molecule {CHMid: \"%s\", smiles:\"%s\"})" % (reagent[0], reagent[1], reagent[2])
        session.run(cypher)
        print cypher
        cypher = "CREATE (%s)-[:REAGENT]->(%s)" %(reagent[0], reaction[0])
        print cypher
        session.run(cypher)
     
    for product in products:            
        cypher = "CREATE (%s:Molecule {CHMid: \"%s\", smiles:\"%s\"})" % (product[0], product[1], product[2])
        session.run(cypher)
        print cypher
        cypher = "CREATE (%s)-[:PRODUCT]->(%s)" %(reaction[0], product[0])
        session.run(cypher)   
        print cypher

reagents1 = []
reagents1.append(["Chem2","nbutylamine","CCCCN"])
reagents1.append(["Chem3","butanoicAcid","CCCCOO"])

products1 =[]
products1.append(["Chem1","Nbutylbutanamide","CCCCNC(O)CCCC"])

reaction1 = ["Reaction1", "reaction1", "AmideFormation"]

addReactionNeo4j(reagents1, products1, reaction1)


session.close()
```

This code should write cypher code and execute it in Neo4j.

It gives the following cypher code as output

```
CREATE (Reaction1:Reaction {RXNid:"reaction1", name:"AmideFormation"})
CREATE (Chem2:Molecule {CHMid: "nbutylamine", smiles:"CCCCN"})
CREATE (Chem2)-[:REAGENT]->(Reaction1)
CREATE (Chem3:Molecule {CHMid: "butanoicAcid", smiles:"CCCCOO"})
CREATE (Chem3)-[:REAGENT]->(Reaction1)
CREATE (Chem1:Molecule {CHMid: "Nbutylbutanamide ", smiles:"CCCCNC(O)CCCC"})
CREATE (Reaction1)-[:PRODUCT]->(Chem1)
```

This code works as expected when pasted into Neo4J

[image]

But if I look the graph created by the code (which in theory should be executing the same cypher code) I get the nodes created but it has problems linking the nodes together with edges - leaving the nodes unconnected.

[image]

Can anyone advise me on what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution.

It appears if in neo4j I run

```
CREATE (Reaction1:Reaction {RXNid:"reaction1", name:"AmideFormation"})
CREATE (Chem2:Molecule {CHMid: "nbutylamine", smiles:"CCCCN"})
CREATE (Chem3:Molecule {CHMid: "butanoicAcid", smiles:"CCCCOO"})
CREATE (Chem1:Molecule {CHMid: "Nbutylbutanamide", smiles:"CCCCNC(O)CCCC"})
```

and then run ...

```
CREATE (Chem2)-[:REAGENT]->(Reaction1)
CREATE (Chem3)-[:REAGENT]->(Reaction1)
CREATE (Reaction1)-[:PRODUCT]->(Chem1)
```

I can replicate the problems with connecting nodes. However if I run them at the same time everything is fine.

Changing my code therefore to use MATCH and MERGE instead of simply create gets round the problem....

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase, basic_auth

driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost", auth=basic_auth("neo4j", "arthuc01"))
session = driver.session()


def addReactionNeo4j(reagents, products, reaction):
    reagents = reagents1
    products = products1
    reaction = reaction1

    cypher = "MERGE (%s:Reaction {RXNid:\"%s\", name:\"%s\"})" % (reaction[0],reaction[1],reaction[2])
    session.run(cypher)
    print cypher

    for reagent in reagents:
        #USe MERGE to only add reagent/product or reaction in already if not:
        cypher = "MERGE (%s:Molecule {CHMid: \"%s\", smiles:\"%s\"})" % (reagent[0], reagent[1], reagent[2])
        session.run(cypher)
        print cypher

        cypher = "MATCH (m:Molecule {CHMid: \"%s\"} ), (r:Reaction {RXNid:\"%s\"})  \
                  MERGE (m)-[:REAGENT]->(r)" %(reagent[0], reaction[0])

        print cypher
        session.run(cypher)


    for product in products:
        #Check if product in already if not:
        cypher = "MERGE (%s:Molecule {CHMid: \"%s\", smiles:\"%s\"})" % (product[0], product[1], product[2])
        print cypher
        session.run(cypher)


        cypher = "MATCH (m:Molecule {CHMid: \"%s\"}), (r:Reaction {RXNid:\"%s\"}) \
                  MERGE (r)-[:PRODUCT]->(m)" %(product[0], reaction[0])
        print cypher
        session.run(cypher)


#        temp =""
#        for cypher in nodes:
#            temp = temp + cypher
#        session.run(temp)    
#            
reagents1 = []
reagents1.append(["Chem2","Chem2","CCCCN"])
reagents1.append(["Chem3","Chem3","CCCCOO"])

products1 =[]
products1.append(["Chem1","Chem1","CCCCNC(O)CCCC"])

reaction1 = ["reaction1", "reaction1", "AmideFormation"]

addReactionNeo4j(reagents1, products1, reaction1)


session.close()
```